# Issue writing non-ascii content to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have the below functionality in node:

1. Read the html contents from a web-url
2. Convert the content to pdf using html-pdf package (using streams)
3. Upload the content to s3 using this stream as the body

When the HTML contains non ASCII characters, for example Chinese or Korean language contents, the PDF uploaded shows blank for these characters

If I try writing to the file locally, the pdf saved shows the contents properly.

I tried setting ContentEncoding to UTF-8, still facing the properly.

Comment: Instead of using streams, you could write the file locally, then use `CopyObject()` to copy the whole file to S3.

Comment: thanks for help. I have a Lambda to this , so writing file locally is not an option

Comment: You can write to `/tmp` in Lambda, but there is only 500MB of storage available. So, you can write to a local file, then copy the file to S3. Be sure to delete the file afterwards because Lambda containers can be reused and you don't want to run out of storage space.

Comment: thank you for response. Is there a way to include some headers for content encoding or specifiying utf-8 when i use putObject? 

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=174119

This said, the /tmp contents can disappear anytime hence was confused. So i understand the file will be available during the execution of the lambda

Comment: The copy command will copy the _exact contents_ of the file. There is no need to set any encoding. The contents of `/tmp` will remain during execution of the Lambda function and will continue to persist until the container is destroyed.

Comment: Thankss John.  there is no way to upload contents  to s3 directly when text contains non-ascii characters?

I am not comfortable in writing to tmp, if the lambda executions are many and for storage concerns

Comment: That's funny -- I'm not comfortable writing to a stream! Since you say that your code works fine if saved locally, then save it to `/tmp` and copy it to S3. There will be no impact due to "many lambda executions" -- each execution is run separately. As long as your file doesn't exceed 500MB and you delete it after use, you'll be fine!

Comment: Thanks John for clarification.  With not comfortable, i meant i was not sure if the storage would be an issue if the concurrent lambda calls are high

I cannot use CopyObject as this function lets only existing s3 file as the source and not the local file.

Comment: Sorry, CopyObject is not correct. You can use UploadFile. I'll add a Python example.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein it was font issue
Including fonts under the deployment package fixed the problem
thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to create the file locally, then copy it to Amazon S3.

Here is an example in Python:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.upload_file('/tmp/hello.txt', 'mybucket', 'hello.txt')
```

Make sure to delete the file after upload, to provide storage space for future executions of the function.

Comment: Thank you

I am trying to find javascript equivalent for this as i am using node.js

Comment: Javascript SDK does not support uploadFile

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html